# How to read the data or attributes from the xml node "OuterXml"

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="latest_ob.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<current_observation version="1.0" >
    </image>
    <suggested_pickup>15 minutes after the hour</suggested_pickup>
    <suggested_pickup_period>60</suggested_pickup_period>
    <temp_f>44.0</temp_f>
    <temp_c>6.7</temp_c>
    <relative_humidity>55</relative_humidity>
    <wind_string>North at 6.9 MPH (6 KT)</wind_string>
    <wind_dir>North</wind_dir>
    <wind_degrees>340</wind_degrees>
    <wind_mph>6.9</wind_mph>
    <wind_kt>6</wind_kt>
    <pressure_string>1025.2 mb</pressure_string>
    <pressure_mb>1025.2</pressure_mb>
    <pressure_in>30.28</pressure_in>
    <dewpoint_string>28.9 F (-1.7 C)</dewpoint_string>
    <dewpoint_f>28.9</dewpoint_f>
    <dewpoint_c>-1.7</dewpoint_c>
</current_observation>
```

I want to get some attributes lik `wind_dir`,`wind_kt` etc from the above xml data. I have tried this:

```
var dayt = GetXMLAsString(WeatherXML);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(dayt);

var r = from element in doc.Elements()
        where element.Name == "latitude"
        select element;

foreach (var item in r)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

I want this data to be converted into an array or model to send it to ajax result .

Comment: Just FYI your XML is malformed: there is a closing tag `</image>` without a corresponding opening tag. Also please show it prettier, everything on one line != human readable.

Comment: Thankyou. Actually that might not be the issue. just got the result.Writing down the way here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this earlier but kept ".value":

var a = from hash in doc.Descendants("latitude")
                        select hash.value;

I got proper result when i tried as follows: 
  XmlDocument WeatherXML = new XmlDocument();
                WeatherXML.Load(reader);

```
            var dayt = GetXMLAsString(WeatherXML);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(dayt);
```

var a = from hash in doc.Descendants("latitude")
                    select hash;

```
            var asdd = from hash in doc.Descendants("current_observation")
                    select hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of System.Xml.Linq namespace we have a set of convenient methods to call.
In your case following code can help:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(WeatherXML);
var value = from e in doc.Elements()
            where e.Name == "wind_kt"
            select e.Value;
```